# What topics to review before starting organic chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry

It's been over a semester since my most recent chemistry class, (general chemistry 2) because I could not take organic at my community college. It is only considered a sophomore level class unless taken in-residence at the university I am transferring to (which is understandable.)

I was curious if I could narrow down what topics I could begin reviewing before the start of the semester that would help me in organic chemistry.

Comment: Bonding, hybridization, and resonance seem the most vital to me. Welcome to chem.SE, but this raises my alarms as primarily opinion-based. We can never know how much time you have, how much you're gonna spend on them etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really need a study tutorial or anything, just topics in lower level general chemistry that apply to organic chemistry, it seems like that lies in the realm of the factual.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, FTW pretty much everything in chem101 and chem102 will be needed for organochem studies, depending on how deep you wanna dig in.

Comment: Understanding Aromaticity, huckel's rule and conjugation will be helpful.

Comment: @LiamH, OP is asking about *prerequisites* for an organic chemistry course, you're talking about the actual *content* of it. The concepts you mentioned are undoubtedly important, but they are introduced in the course itself, OP does not need to know them before entering the course.

Comment: As @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M pointed out, the usual prerequisite for an organic chemistry course is that a general chemistry course is already taken and successfully passed. Topics include:  atomic theory, periodic table, nomenclature, stoichiometry, bonding, molecular geometry, basic types of reactions, acids and bases, solubility, thermodynamics, kinetics, coordination chemistry.

Comment: @Wild "Meow" Cat - That's one good answer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

As @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M pointed out in his comment, the usual prerequisite for an organic chemistry course is that a *general chemistry* course is already taken and successfully passed. The general chemistry is, of course, a rather large topic, so I'll just name a few subtopics which I feel are absolutely essential to start a venture into the world of organic chemistry.

1. Structure of matter.

   - Modern atomic theory (Schrödinger equation, atomic orbitals, spin,  Pauli exclusion principle, electron configurations).
   - The periodic table (periodicity, group trends).
   - Chemical bonding (covalent and ionic bonding, Lewis structures, resonance, [VSEPR theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) , introductory [Valence Bond Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_bond_theory) and [Molecular Orbital Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory)).
2. Chemical reactions.

   - Nomenclature & stoichiometry (empirical and molecular formulas, chemical equations, mole, limiting reagents, yield).
   - Solutions (solubility, concentration, properties of solutions).
   - Acid-base reactions (definitions of acids and bases, pH, strong/weak acids and bases, trends).
   - Oxidation-reduction reactions (oxidation numbers, balancing oxidation-reduction reactions).
3. Thermodynamics.

   - Basic concepts (energy, work, heat, enthalpy, entropy, Gibbs free energy ).
   - The first and the second laws of thermodynamics.
   - Hess's law.
4. Kinetics.

   - Reaction rates (temperature dependence, Arrhenius equation).
   - Reaction orders (first and second order reactions, molecularity, rate laws).
   - Catalysis.
5. Chemical equilibrium.

   - Basic principles (the notion of equilibrium, the law of mass action, equilibrium constants, the direction of a reaction).
   - Shifting the equilibrium (changing amounts, pressure, volume, temperature).